# When finding electric potential and electric potential energy is it all adding the total?

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, potential, potential-energy

I am not sure what the difference is between the two. For example, when I add the total of all the potential for every point charge isn t that finding the potential energy since you also add all the pairs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Potential energy is a single number: it is the energy associated with a configuration of charges. It is the work you must do against the Coulomb forces to assemble said configuration, bringing each charge in from infinity.

Potential is a scalar field: it is a number attached to every point in space. It is defined as the unique function (up to a constant term) such that the E-field is its negative [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient):
$$\vec E = -\vec \nabla V$$

If you have two charges $q_1$ and $q_2$ separated by a distance $d$, the potential energy of this configuration (which you should prove yourself) is
$$W = q_2V_{12} = q_1V_{21}=\frac{q_1q_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0d}$$
where $V_{12}$ is the potential only due to charge $q_1$ at the location of $q_2$, and vice versa. When you have a collection of point charges, the total energy will be a sum of such terms for each pair. It is unclear what you mean by "adding the total of all the potential for every point charge" and why you think the pairwise sum of potentials appearing in the energy expression means potential is the same as potential energy, so if you are still confused, please clarify your question.

Comment: What I didn't understand was when you find potential energy of a group of multiple point charge, you add the individual potential energies between each pair to find the total. However, isn't this the same for finding the electric potential of a bunch of point charge?

Comment: @Muse I'm having trouble understanding where the confusion is. Again, potential energy is a property of a configuration of charges, whereas there is no such thing as the "potential of a charge configuration". Even still, when you calculate the total potential energy, you are adding the potential energies of each pair of charges, you are not adding potentials. Perhaps you can clarify your question by including some math.

Comment: For example, if I have point charge 1,2,3 and I need to find the potential energy of the system, I would be adding the potential energy of every unique pair with the formula U=kq1q2/r. If it ask me to find the electric potential of the system how would I do this? Would I again add all the potential of the unique charges using V=Es? If I do then for the "q" value in the E which point charge do I use?

Comment: @Muse As I've tried to explain, there is no such thing as the electric potential of the system. You can only speak of a potential at a certain point.

Comment: So basically a question can only ask for the electric potential between two points? If I had two different charged point charge (-2 and +4) in the equation (V=Kq/R) which q value do I input?

Comment: @Muse You can only speak of the potential *at a certain point*, not the potential between charges. You can speak of the potential at the location of charge 2 due to charge 1, in which case you would use charge 1 in the calculation.

Comment: Ah! I get it so basically electric potential is a measure of the potential of a certain source charge at various locations.

Comment: @Muse Yes, each charge results in a potential at a given location. The total potential at this location is the sum of the potentials due to each charge.